# Define a URL pattern to not hit Spring Controller method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.2

I have a requirement to show the localized version of page if user hits /fr to internally treat it as ?language=fr_FR and show the french translations

But currently spring treats /fr for a controller method.

How can i make sure that the TWO characters i define after "/" , spring treats it as language instead of request for a controller method.

Comment: check this link: http://christophstrobl.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/sping-mvc-howto-use-path-variable-in-with-i18n-localechangeinterceptor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/action/{language}")
public class TesteController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String doSomething(@PathVariable String language) {
        if (language.equals("fr")) {
            // do something
        }
    }

}
```

So you can type /action/fr , /action/en, etc.

Comment: How do I ensure that {language} can have only two characters ?

Comment: I do not want /action/postme to go to this controller method

Comment: You need to verify the variable value and return the user an error. You can't limit the characters.

Comment: You mean there cannot be any regex for 2 characters ?

Comment: What @PathVariable does is not more than a parsing of the URL. It replaces the pattern you defined by the value informed on the URL. You could make a custom annotation that check by the pattern you want and deny access to the method.

Comment: Maybe too late, but yes PathVariables can have regex it will be like `/action/{language:[regex]}`, the pattern is {var:regex}